# File not found error in jenkinsfile script

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, flask, jenkins-pipeline

Can anyone explain why I get the following error : + python unittests.py
python: can't open file 'unittests.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This is my jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('prepare') {
         steps {
            git credentialsId: 'git-cred', url: 'https://github.com/nada809/DockerProject.git'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        agent {
            docker {
                 image 'python:3.8-slim-buster'
            }
        }
        steps {
            
             sh 'pip install flask && pip install xmlrunner'
             dir("app"){
             sh 'python unittests.py'}
        }
        
    }
   
        
        
    }
}
```

And this is my project structure:
[image]

the unittests file is under app folder.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add some bash cmd to list files under app before run unittest.py.  For example: sh 'pwd && ls- l'

Answer (score 0):

"main" seems to be your new default branch (which is empty). Please try to

1. merge your "master" branch into "main" or
2. set your "master" branch as your default again or
3. define "master" explicitly in your git step

Fyi: seems like GitHub did apply their recent [plan to get rid off "master" branches](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/)